# API or query tool for USGS Protected Areas Database of the United States?

Tags: land, usgs

Is there an API or query tool for something like this PAD-US system? I want to determine if GPS coordinates are public land or private land.  I could only see downloads or ESRI maps available.

PAD-US is America’s official national inventory of U.S. terrestrial and marine protected areas (List of National Geospatial Data Assets) that are dedicated to the preservation of biological diversity and to other natural, recreation, and cultural uses, managed for these purposes through legal or other effective means.

[Link](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/science-analytics-and-synthesis/gap/science/pad-us-data-overview?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects)